# Need something like wait or delay in corona sdk

Tags: timer, lua, transition, coronasdk

Im making a game in corona. I'm searching for something to make a stop in my code for 5 seconds. I found timer.performwith delay, but it's not working, i need something that stops all the code for 5 seconds. Can someone help me with that please?

I want to make after this transition to wait for 5 seconds and the continue with the code.

```
transition.to(block[old], {time=tranTime, x=block[new].x, y=block[new].y})
transition.to(block[new], {time=tranTime, x=block[old].x, y=block[old].y})
```

Answer (score 2):

```
local function yourFunction()
  print("This will get called 5seconds after block[old] transition...")
end

local function transitionFinished()
  print("Transition of block[old] is completed...")
  timer.performWithDelay(5000,yourFunction,1) --[[ If you want, you can use this 
                                                   line to call 'yourFunction' 
                                                   after desired time(here 5seconds) 
                                              --]]
end

transition.to(block[old], {time=tranTime, x=block[new].x, y=block[new].y, onComplete=transitionFinished})
transition.to(block[new], {time=tranTime, x=block[old].x, y=block[old].y})
```

Or else, if you want to pause all the transitions, there are many custom classes and you can make use of something like one that DevfaR said.

Or if you want to perform a transition after a delay, you can also use:

```
transition.to(block[old], {delay=1000,time=tranTime, x=block[new].x, y=block[new].y}) 
-- this will get called after a delay of 1000ms --
```

Keep coding............ :)

Comment: `timer.performWithDelay(5000, yourFunction)` is enough if you want the function to be called once. The third param, which is number of iterations, is optional.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to stop code for a certain amount of time but what you can do is use the onComplete event in the transition. For example:

```
local function1 = function()
    print("This will show after the transition finishes.")
end

transition.to(block[old], {time=tranTime, x=block[new].x, y=block[new].y, onComplete=function1})
transition.to(block[new], {time=tranTime, x=block[old].x, y=block[old].y})
```